# how to select an element from one div to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to do select an anchor from one div to another using next() , shiblings(), parents(), parent() etc jquery functions

### Here is an example of html

```
<div class="thumbs">
   <div class="section">
      <div class="wrap">
         <a href="link.php" data-selector="ajax">HOme</a>
      </div>
   </div>
<div>
<div class="thumbs">
   <div class="section">
      <div class="wrap">
         <a href="link2.php" data-selector="ajax">about</a>
      </div>
   </div>
<div>
```

i want to get the second link.Suppose my current link is `link.php` and when i click th next button i want to get next `link2.php` link

Comment: You want to get the whole element (a), or just the href part from it?

Comment: just the link in th href

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
$('[data-selector="ajax"].current')
      .closest('.thumbs')
          .next()
             .find('a')
               .attr("href"); // will return link2.php
```

Comment: Edited to produce the exact result the asker wanted.

Comment: there comes undefined

Comment: @SumaiyaSalam: how do you distinguished active element?? does it have unique class/attribute??

Comment: there is no active class, there is no jquery library involved. please go ahead and do that first